# Use of return function

Tags: python, return

Below is my answer for [14. Longest Common Prefix in Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/):

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        ans = ""
        if len(strs) == 0 or strs is None:
            return None
        p = len(min(strs,key=len))
        for i in range(p):
            current = strs[0][i]
            for j in range(len(strs)):
                if current != strs[j][i]:
                    return ans
            ans += current
        return ans
```

When the input is "" (empty string), why it returns "" instead of None? Isn't the function supposed to end in the "if" clause in the beginning? Thank you very much!!

Comment: And you don't have to `return None` just `return` is enough

Comment: yes ``strs`` is a list of strings

Comment: You should say `if not strs:`.  That covers empty strings and empty lists, as well as `None`.